# Extract array from connector array

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

It seems that it is at least not encouraged to write Modelica functions with connectors as arguments. I get a warning if I try it.

Assume I have a connector

```
connector con
  Real x;
  Real y;
end con;
```

a record

```
record rec
  Real x;
  Real y;
end rec;
```

and a function

```
function f
  input rec r[:];
  output Real z;
algorithm
  ...
end f;
```

Given an array of connectors, i.e. `con c[N]`, how can I convert it into an array of records `rec`?

One approach would be to use a function

```
function convert
  input Integer N;
  input Real x[N];
  input Real y[N];
  output rec z[N];
algorithm 
  z.x := x;
  z.y := y;
end convert;
```

and call it via `convert(size(c, 1), c.x, c.y)`.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Oops, that was easy. You are right. Thanks.

Comment: I generalized the question.

Comment: It might work with r = c; without any function but i'm not 100% sure.
Or with r.x = c.x; r.y = c.y;